# SignalR client on Android Studio is always on disconnected state

Tags: java, android, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to implement client side socket in android studio to display data from iotHub. But i am unable to do that. Currently in my code i get disconnected state.
I am little confused my server side is up and running fine but i am trying to make a client in android studio using sockets.

My java file

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    HubConnection hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http:e.g").withTransport(TransportEnum.LONG_POLLING).build();
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMain);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);
    Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSend);
     editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMessageText);


    List<String> messageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messageList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    hubConnection.on("Send", (message)-> {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                arrayAdapter.add(message);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }, String.class);



    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            editText.setText("");
            try {
                hubConnection.send("Send", message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    new HubConnectionTask().execute(hubConnection);

}

class HubConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<HubConnection, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(HubConnection... hubConnections) {
        HubConnection hubConnection = hubConnections[0];
        hubConnection.start();
        editText.setText(hubConnection.getConnectionState().toString());
        if(hubConnection.getConnectionState()== HubConnectionState.CONNECTED){
            editText.setText("Sent");

        }
        return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: to make sure that messages are being sent to ioTHub can you check that they are arriving using for example the [Azure IoT Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-tools) in VSCode?

Comment: Hey did you have the time to check suggestion? If your issue is solved please post the solution as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Was this resolved? I got the same problem.